# Prevent android default browser zoom on landscape mode

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications

landscape mode / qwerty keyboard mode zooms in android default browser.. 
any way to avoid this?
the zoom behavior that is..

using device:  Droid 4

also, it might be important to note, im using this meta tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: What's zooming? Fonts? Graphics?

Comment: The whole page zooms, about 4x that of portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oddly enough, scrolling to top on landscape was causing it:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a zooming problem on fonts / UI...

Use this CSS tag.

```
  html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; /* Never autoresize text */
    }
```

Comment: The entire page is zooming, this would only prevent, as you said, font/UI from zooming